# using `when` and `in` inside of IF clause

Tags: sql, postgresql

Would using a `when` and `in` clause work when using `IF` clauses?

E.g

```
IF (when regexp_replace(lower(value), '\s+$', '') in (
     'some string',
     'another string'
 )) then

   // do stuff
```

Comment: There is no `IF` in SQL

Answer (score 1):

No, and you don't need to combine different conditionals in the same statement. Stick to one of them, e.g. `IF`. You can test it yourself using an [`anonymous code block`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/13/plpython-do.html):

```
DO $$
DECLARE value text := 'another string';
BEGIN
 IF (regexp_replace(lower(value), '\s+$', '') IN 
    ('some string','another string')) THEN
    -- do something
  END IF;
END;
$$
```